Left aligning two columns of text
I want to have to columns of text on the opposite sides of the page that both will be left aligned. I have the following LaTeX code so far:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X >{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X }
        \textbf{Seller} & \textbf{Buyer} \\
        John Smith & Jane Smith
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}

Which produces:

But still the text on the right isn't left aligned. Is there any other way to achieve my goal?

You could use an l column to left align the second column:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl}
        \textbf{Seller} & \textbf{Buyer} \\
        John Smith & Jane Smith
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}



Wow it was easier than I expected, thank you. One more question, when I put \textbf{Invoice number} above the table, it looks like the table is shifted slightly to the right. Can I do anything with that?

@RafalMaziejuk Are you maybe looking for \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Xl@{}}? If not please post a new question including a [mre]
